# Convergence in distribution of measures defined by a sequence converging in distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to prove the next:

Suppose $F_n\Rightarrow F_0$ and $g\geq 0$ is continuous and satisfies $\int_{\mathbb{R}}gdF_n = 1$ for every $n\geq 0.$ Define the measure $$G_n(A) = \int_{A}gdF_n.$$ Then $G_n\Rightarrow G_0.$

I was utilizing "epsilon" definition of convergence of $F_n$ because $G_n$ is a particular way in which the convergence is possible ($g$ is continuous over all real numbers) but I cannot see a way to bounded with the integral of $g$ respect $F_n$ measure over real numbers.

A suggestion is to prove this directly or use Scheffé lemma but, how can be possible to get a density function for g?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.